# Changes in Microsoft Outlook inbox icons version 2010 - 2019

Tags: outlook

I noticed that certain inbox mail icons have disappeared / got a new index in Outlook 2019.
The one icon I'm specifically looking for used to have icon index 275 in Outlook 2010 (secure reply, http://davton.com/blog/changing-the-icon-for-an-outlook-message/).
In Outlook 2010, when I assign this icon to an email via

```
private void SetIconOnMail(IRDOMail mail)
{
   var PR_ICON_INDEX = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10800003";
   mail.Fields[PR_ICON_INDEX] = 275
}
```

everything works correctly.

However, when I use the same method in Outlook 2019, it shows the following icon on an email:

[image: The new icon with index 275]

Is the original `secure reply` icon no longer available in Outlook 2019 or does it have a new index?

Thanks in advance.